# Why does java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException happen on this piece of code?

Tags: java, netbeans

```
public boolean felGissningar(char gi, int antalfel){
    if(antalfel>0){
    int test = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<felGiss1.length; i++){
        if(gi == felGiss1[i]){
            test+=1;
        }
    }
    felGiss2 = new char[antalfel];
    for (int i = 0; i<felGiss1.length; i++){
        felGiss2[i]=felGiss1[i];
    }

    felGiss1 = new char[antalfel+1];
    for (int i =0;i<antalfel; i++){
        felGiss1[i]=felGiss2[i];
    }
    felGiss1[antalfel] = gi;
    System.out.println("1: "+String.valueOf(felGiss1));
    System.out.println("2: "+String.valueOf(felGiss2));
    if(test>0){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    }else {
        felGiss1 = new char[1];
        felGiss1[0]=gi;
        return true;
    }
}
```

antalfel means number of incorrect answers

After this boolean has returned false once it says java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

what im trying to do is to not allow for the same wrong character twise.

Comment: Where is ```felGiss1``` and ```felGiss2``` declared?

Comment: Which line does the error refer to?

Comment: You didn't tell us **where** the exception occurs. I can only assume it's here `for (int i = 0; i<felGiss1.length; i++){
        felGiss2[i]=felGiss1[i];
    }`

Comment: At the top, outside of the function. felGiss1 and felGiss2 is declared

Comment: NetBeans does not say where the exception occurs, so im not sure.

Comment: You should get a stacktrace, where it says the exact line numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over here:

```java
    felGiss2 = new char[antalfel];
    for (int i = 0; i<felGiss1.length; i++){
        felGiss2[i]=felGiss1[i];
    }
```

Since you didn't post where `felGiss1` was created, if `felGiss1.length` is greater than `felGiss2.length` then it will produce an exception. Please change to:

```java
    felGiss2 = new char[antalfel];
    for (int i = 0; i<felGiss1.length && i < fellGiss2.length; i++){
        felGiss2[i]=felGiss1[i];
    }
```